# Java: how to use inner class definition in main function

Tags: java, variables, inner-classes

So I have this program . Example shown below just for demonstration:

```
class Rest{
public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
Rest restful = new Rest();
Rest.config conf = new Rest.config();
        }
    });
}

class config{}
}
```

So what I want to do is define a variable that uses the config class as definition in the main function . The reason why I want to use config as a inner class is because it uses some variables and functions of rest.

I do not want to declare config as a static class either .

Cheers,

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: Please show a proper, complete example - currently your `main` method declaration is syntactically incorrect to start with before you even get to the body... And do you really need this to be an *inner* class as opposed to just a *nested* class?

Comment: Yes I need an inner class .

Comment: You say it should be inner, but if you understand the difference between inner classes and static nested classes, you wouldn't be trying to do that. What is the enclosing instance of the `config` you are trying to create?

Comment: You mean I should do it this way instead : restful.config conf .... I tried that didnt work . I am just asking how to access that . I do not want to change config to static either

Comment: The way to instantiate a `config` is `Rest.config conf = new Rest().new config();`. I strongly suggest you use a static nested class instead. By the way, class names in java should begin with capital letters.

Comment: why . I am using some variables and function from the outer class . Yea tried that now it is good .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `new Rest.config()` syntax.  That only works for static inner classes.  You need to use `new Rest().new Config();` or `restful.new Config();`

In the future, you'll get a better response if your code is correct and formatted properly.

Tutorial: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)